# pandas fillna depend on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
A    B
a    15
a    15
a    NaN
b    19
b    NaN
```

I want to fillna column B with 15 if column A vlaue is 'a', and column B with 19 if column A vlaue is 'b', and result is following dataframe:

```
A    B
a    15
a    15
a    15
b    19
b    19
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble believing this is really your problem. Can you ensure that this toy will generalise to your actual problem?

Comment: It's just a example. My actual problem is similar to this.

Comment: This is not clear.  You've not offered any convincing concrete reason to deduce why b's map to 19 and a's map to 15.  I'm concerned that if I give the absolute obvious answer, you'll turn about and say "That isn't what I meant".  So instead, I'd rather you be clearer about what you mean up front.  Also, please show your effort.  What you've tried will shed light on your intent.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is sorted, you can use `ffill`.

```
df.ffill()
```

Output:

Or if it isn't sorted, you can use `sort_values` and `ffill`:

```
df.sort_values(['A','B']).ffill()
```

Output:

```
   A     B
0  a  15.0
1  a  15.0
2  a  15.0
3  b  19.0
4  b  19.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(df['A']=='a') & df['B'].isnull(), 'B'] = 15
df.loc[(df['A']=='b') & df['B'].isnull(), 'B'] = 19
```

Perhaps the `df['B'].isnull()` clause is not necessary - if all 'a' and 'b' rows in the column B must be 15 or 19, anyway.